# Writing to global memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I would like to ask about the effect of writing to global memory in CUDA. It is known that global memory reads often have great impact to the performance (coalescing, caches, bank conflicts) since they may require quite a lot of cycles to wait for the incoming memory, which may block the execution at a moment.

However what about a writing memory in CUDA? Does it suffer from any type of memory write pattern? Is the total cost straightforwardly is the sum of all the writes in the kernel?

Any related references and comments would be appreciated.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of question that would be fun to explore using an experimental program.  You could write a basic OpenCL or CUDA program that performs many millions of reads and writes in various patterns.  Run your tests over and over in a loop, and see what you get on average.  It's probably a good way to learn the boring parts of each API to boot.

Comment: Thanks James for the comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general the answer to your question is "yes", stores are similar to loads.  The difference is that since stores are "fire and forget", if there is work to do that does not depend on the stored addresses then that can be immediately run by the multiprocessor(s) after issuing the stores, and stalls will only happen when read-after-write dependencies are encountered.

For full details, I suggest reading section 5.3.2 of the latest [CUDA programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf).

Also see appendix F of that document for specific information pertaining to different architecture families.  For example compute capability 1.x has more performance "cliffs" than compute capability 2.x (Fermi) devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realized most of this theory can be confirmed by microbenchmarking. However, few things getting confused when Fermi coming to the scene. I noticed that before Fermi, there were performance counters for memory coalescencing but now they are gone! Is there any reason behind this? I don't think memory coalescencing has totally no effect in Fermi anymore (for both reads and writes), but rather its concept is complicated by the contribution of caches. So, my guess, that's why NVIDIA removed those counters. Anyone has any  idea about this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The counters were replaced by cache hit/miss counters.  The latest visual profiler version (4.1) makes it much easier to interpret this data, by building useful metrics out of the counters rather than showing raw counter data.  On Fermi, it's all down to the number of cache lines fetched, rather than the number of coalesced memory segments.